# Tracking index position changes with angular-drag-and-drop-lists

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angulardraganddroplists

I am making use of [angular-drag-and-drop-lists](https://github.com/marceljuenemann/angular-drag-and-drop-lists) and have a simple list of items that I wish to re-order.

I have this working, but I want to be able to capture the old and new index position for an item being moved.

I have attempted to this using `dnd-moved` and `dnd-inserted` as per my code below.

**Markup:**

```
<ul dnd-list="vm.route.stops"
        dnd-inserted="vm.stopInserted(index)">
          <li ng-repeat="stop in vm.route.stops"
              dnd-draggable="stop"
              dnd-moved="vm.stopMoved($index)"
              dnd-effect-allowed="move">
              <span>{{$index + 1}}.</span>
              <md-card style="width:280px;">
                <div layout="row">
                    {{stop.location}}
                </div>
              </md-card>
          </li>
      </ul>
```

Controller:

```
public stopMoved = (index: number) => {
    const stop = this.route.stops[index];
    console.log('Moved stop: ' +  stop.name + ' from position: ' + index);
    this.route.stops.splice(index, 1);
  }

  public stopInserted = (index: number) => {
    const stop = this.route.stops[index];
    console.log('Inserted stop: ' +  stop.name + ' at position: ' + index);
  }
```

The problem I am finding is that the output index values for when a stop is moved and inserted are not what I expect.

I think I may be hitting upon something mentioned in the docs for the dnd-inserted attribute:

> Note that for reorderings inside the same list the old element will
>   still be in the list due to the fact that dnd-moved was not called yet

So consider I have four items added to my list.

[image]

I then move 'Covent Garden' down to where 'Waterloo Bridge' was:

[image]

Console output correctly shows it was moved from index 0 but says inserted at index 3 (I was hoping it would say 2)

[image]

The `dnd-inserted` function is being invoked before `dnd-moved`, which follows the quote I referenced further above from the docs.

If I move items in the other direction, so from bottom to top, I see similar behaviour with the captured indexes.

So starting as follows:

[image]

I move 'Blackfriars' to where 'Southwark' was:

[image]

Console output reads as:

[image]

I would expect to see that it had moved from index 3 instead.

I am probably misunderstanding something fundamental with using this library. Is there a clean way to track old and new index positions of items after them have been removed\inserted in a vertical list with this library?

Thanks

Comment: If you are selecting library for dnd to use -- never take this one.

Comment: Care to suggest any alternatives? What's so bad about this library?

Comment: I spent some time on it - and this is my conclusion: First html5 drag drop is not ready yet for real applications in general. Second, this library is bad designed and i.e. for virtual lists it will just not work.